# Toggle Mobile Broadband network connection

Tags: windows, powershell, wireless

I'm looking for a way to toggle Mobile broadband connection on and off in Windows 8.1 using PowerShell. If there is no pure PowerShell cmdlet, native `cmd.exe` way may also suffice. Currently, I know how to disable and enable the adapter itself, but not the connection. In case it is important: the PC has built-in 3G module.

I have tried to compare the properties of adapter in connected and disconnected state:

```
Get-NetAdapter -Name "Mobile broadband" | select -Property * | Out-File connected.txt
# manually disconnected
Get-NetAdapter -Name "Mobile broadband" | select -Property * | Out-File disconnected.txt
Compare-Object $(Get-Content connected.txt) $(Get-Content disconnected.txt)
```

And got the following results:

```
  InputObject                                                 SideIndicator
-----------                                                 -------------
Status                                           : Disco... =>
LinkSpeed                                        : 0 bps    =>
MediaConnectionState                             : Disco... =>
ifOperStatus                                     : Down     =>
Speed                                            : 0        =>
InterfaceOperationalStatus                       : 2        =>
MediaConnectState                                : 2        =>
OperationalStatusDownMediaDisconnected           : True     =>
ReceiveLinkSpeed                                 : 0        =>
TransmitLinkSpeed                                : 0        =>
Status                                           : Up       <=
LinkSpeed                                        : 21.6 ... <=
MediaConnectionState                             : Conne... <=
ifOperStatus                                     : Up       <=
Speed                                            : 21600000 <=
InterfaceOperationalStatus                       : 1        <=
MediaConnectState                                : 1        <=
OperationalStatusDownMediaDisconnected           : False    <=
ReceiveLinkSpeed                                 : 5760000  <=
TransmitLinkSpeed                                : 21600000 <=
```

However, it does not seems as I can change any of those options, since they appear as read-only to me:

```
Get-NetAdapter -Name "Mobile broadband" | Get-Member -Name Status,MediaConnectionState,ifOperStatus,InterfaceOperationalStatus,MediaConnectState,OperationalStatusDownMediaDisconnected


   TypeName: Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_NetAdapter

Name                                   MemberType     Definition                                                       
----                                   ----------     ----------                                                       
Status                                 ScriptProperty System.Object Status {get=$NetAdapter = $this;...                
MediaConnectionState                   ScriptProperty System.Object MediaConnectionState {get=[Microsoft.PowerShell....
ifOperStatus                           ScriptProperty System.Object ifOperStatus {get=[Microsoft.PowerShell.Cmdletiz...
InterfaceOperationalStatus             Property       uint32 InterfaceOperationalStatus {get;}                         
MediaConnectState                      Property       uint32 MediaConnectState {get;}                                  
OperationalStatusDownMediaDisconnected Property       bool OperationalStatusDownMediaDisconnected {get;}
```

I also could not change the connection state with Enable-NetAdapter cmdlet.

Comment: I think you should work at adapter level, at least try disabling the connection in the GUI and check if the adapter's WMI object has `NetEnabled` as false. If yes, these actions are plain equal.

Comment: @Vesper I'm sorry, I do not understand exactly what you mean. I have added extra information to the description, maybe it will be useful.

Comment: Hmm, what type of connection is your 3G to the system? Is it a kind of modem/VPN one? I mean, what type of connection is displayed in your "Network connections" window on your 3G? If it is a kind of dialup or VPN, check `Get-VPNConnection` for methods to control the connection.

Comment: @Vesper It does not seem to be a VPN connection, since Get-VPNConnection cannot locate it by either name or * wildcard. I also never entered any credentials. In "Network connections", it simply says "HUAWEI Mobile Broadband Module" and no extra indication of connection type. Also, in Windows 8 GUI, "Networks" section, there is a "Mobile broadband" subsection and a simple slider to toggle it - same as the ones for Airplane Mode and Wi-Fi. Extra note is that connection was detected by freshly installed Windows 8.1 (generic, not a device-specific) without me having to install any extra drivers.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Inrego Nope, still looking for one

Comment: In my experience, cellular modems are NDIS, DUN or Mobile Broadband. This or is *inclusive*, and so many are two or more. Win32-Potsmodem might find it.

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to any kind of network [cannot](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/b0ff3beb-4353-45a0-a9a8-d8334b2a6409/connect-to-wireless-network-via-c-code?forum=peertopeer) be done using the .Net framework. But to connect to a mobile connection you can type `NETSH MBN CONNECT INTERFACE=<ADAPTER_NAME> CONNMODE=NAME NAME=<CONNECTION_PROFILE_NAME>` on a Command Prompt to accomplish this. ADAPTER_NAME would be "Mobile broadband" in your case, and you can find the value of CONNECTION_PROFILE_NAME with the following PowerShell command: `Get-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceAlias "Mobile broadband" | Select-Object Name`

And to disconnect from the network, use `NETSH MBN DISCONNECT <ADAPTER_NAME>`.

Comment: On my system the Get-NetConnectionProfile does not return any data for mobile connections.
Get-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceAlias "Mobiel 5"
Get-NetConnectionProfile : No MSFT_NetConnectionProfile objects found with property 'InterfaceAlias' equal to 'Mobiel 5
'.  Verify the value of the property and retry.
The name is correct and the netsh mbn command works.

Comment: Get-NetConnectionProfile only displays information about connections you are actually connected to, i.e. it doesn't list disconnected WiFi/mobile connections.
So try connecting to 'Mobiel 5' and see if it works.

Comment: My "Mobile" device was connected but I had to disconnect the wifi in order to have Get-NetConnectionProfile list the  properties of the mobile connection. This is logical as the WIFI has a higher priority than the mobile connection. thanks @Cool Charac